# Create an array with repeating numbers

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have this array:

```
1 2 3 4
```

and I want to create an array like this:

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

How could I create that?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for `repelem`:

> repelem Replicate elements of an array.
>       U = repelem(V,N), where V is a vector, returns a vector of repeated
>       elements of V.

So what you want is:

```
>> repelem([1 2 3 4],4)
```